# Almost sure convergence of average of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

In my statistical inference course exercise guide, I am confronted with the following problem:

> Let $0<\theta<1/2$, and define the sequence $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of discrete independent random variables as follows: $X_n$ takes the values $n^{\theta}$ and $-n^{\theta}$ with probabilities $P(X_n=n^{\theta})=1/2=P(X_n=-n^{\theta})$. Show that 
>   $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k \to 0$$
>   almost surely.

**My attempt:** I try to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma. If $\overline{X}_n$ denotes the average of the first $n$ variables, it would suffice to show that for every $\epsilon >0$ it holds that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|{\overline{X}_n}| \geq \epsilon) < \infty \tag{1}$$
A quick computation tells us that for each $n$, we have $E[X_n] = 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_n) = n^{2\theta}$, which implies $E[\overline{X}_n]=0$ and
$$\operatorname{Var}(\overline{X}_n) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\operatorname{Var}(X_k) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2\theta} \tag{2}$$
If we use Chebyshev's inequality, plugging $(2)$ into $(1)$ would yield 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|{\overline{X}_n}| \geq \epsilon) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\operatorname{Var}(\overline{X}_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2\theta}$$ 
The last term of the previous inequality seems quite divergent. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try to combine Kronecker's lemma with the three series theorem (see Wikipedia).

Comment: This follows from Kolmogorov's strong law. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2416698/321264) answer.