# Sum of sequence of real random variables converges to $1$

Tags: probability

Suppose $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of independent real random variables. If now $\mathbb{P}\left[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n}=1\right] > 0$, we have that $\frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n} \rightarrow 1$ with probability $1$. 
How do I even start in proving this? I'm so confused...

Comment: Can you use the law of large number in your problem?

Comment: I have no idea whether this is actually true or not. But here are some observations: there are laws of large numbers for not-identically distributed random variables (see, for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416665/law-of-large-numbers-for-non-identically-distributed-bernoulli-random-variables or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150615/references-for-kolmogorovs-strong-law-of-a-large-numbers). I am not very familiar with these statements but it seems that you need a handle on the second moments, which I'm not sure in this case is possible.

Comment: On one hand, as the event $\{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n} = 1\}$ is not a tail event, you cannot use Kolmogorov's 0-1 law, while on the other, although the event is in the exchangeable sigma-algebra, you cannot use Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law because $X_n$'s are not identically distributed.